# How to split the following string and find out booking id

Tags: string, vb.net, quotes, having

I have following string  in a line of the text file :

```
string = "BOOKINGID=["15786176","priyanka.b.bhardwaj@ericsson.com"]"
```

I need to get 15786176 as a result.

```
Dim line as String()="BOOKINGID=["15786176","priyanka.b.bhardwaj@ericsson.com"]"
Arrayline = line.Split("=")
Dim tmparr As String() = Arrayline(1).Split(",")        ' Regex.Split(Arrayline(1), pattern)
                    Dim BookingIDrr As String() = tmparr(0).Split("[")(1).Split("\""")
```

My code giving "15786176" while I need only 15786176. how to remove these extra double quotes (")

Answer (score 1):

You can try `split('"')` on the entire line into `array` and just getting `array[2]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using regular expressions:

```
Dim Regex As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
Dim SubjectString As String = "BOOKINGID=[""15786176"",""priyanka.b.bhardwaj@ericsson.com""]"
Dim ResultString As String = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, ".*""(\d+)"".*", "$1")
Console.WriteLine(ResultString)
```

This prints:

```
15786176
```

The regex pattern used is `.*""(\d+)"".*`, which says to match a number surrounded by double quotes, which itself is preceded and proceeded by any other content.

Note that the `Regex.Replace` API seems to apply the pattern to the entire string, hence the need for what was used above.